# .htaccess redirect without affecting subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have our main website https://www.example.com.au inside home/user/public_html and a subdomain which lives in home/user/sub https://sub.example.com.au

They are both Joomla websites.

Inside home/user/public_html I have the below .htaccess file which I use to make every page visit of our main website use https and www - the code used is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This above .htaccess file is redirecting all subdomain visits to https:// www. sub.example.com.au - how can I stop it doing so, and at the same time for it to load all the subdomain visits to https: //sub. example.com.au

I thought that the .htaccess file would only affect directories within it, but it seems to be affecting the subdomain even though it isn't within the public_html folder.

Any advise appreciated. Thanks.

Note had to put spaces in some of the links above as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Are you sure your sub-domain is using `/home/user/sub` as it's document root? `.htaccess` files only affect the directory they are in and sub directories. I would assume the issue is that you have a similar `.htaccess` file in the sub domain root, apache isn't setup correctly for the sub domain and is loading the main root or these rules exist in the apache config and so they would affect all sites.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm positive of the directories they are in, and yes the sub directory also has it's own .htaccess (the default Joomla one).

Perhaps you are correct about apache not setting up the domain correctly. I'll try removing and readding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer is to not use a regular expression to match the hostname.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Another option is udpating the virtual host in the Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com.au:80
    ServerAlias www.example.com.au:80
    RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com.au/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com.au:443
    RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com.au/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com.au:443
    # server config goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

However the likely explanation is that the `.htaccess` file has been duplicated in, or symlinked to, the subdomain directory.

Comment: Thanks miken32. I tried the .htaccess changes you recommended (in the public_html .htaccess file and then sub one and it didn't make a difference). The virtual host Apache config is way over my head.

I made changes to the public_html .htaccess file to test and conclude that it is that file that is causing the redirect even though it is in a different directory to the sub....

I've since moved the website onto another web server and it worked as expected straight away...

Comment: @AdamGatt: Please do not accept answers which did not work for you.